# Weird frame when loading video.js

Tags: javascript, video.js

I have Vue app in which I use `"vue-video-player": "^5.0.2",` which use video.js library.

Sometimes when video is loading after I enter page I see weird frame rotating very fast at the bottom right of page. I took 2 screenshots I clicked PrtScr button very fast:

[image]

[image]

It sometimes also happen when video stop because of slow network connection:

[image]

It looks like it's related to loading but I don't think it's spinner. Can I somehow remove/hide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it's related to your loading spinner. To be precise due to the next class:

```
.bg-video__content div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

So your circle spinner just expanded to the whole wrapper size.

Comment: Is there option to hide spinner?

Comment: @BT101 yes. brute-force solution would be adding `.bg-video__content .vjs-loading-spinner {
    display: none;
}` to your styles.